# Listen/follow changes in IBM Cloud Object Storage from Node-JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, object-storage

Does anyone know how to listen to a specific bucket (database) in IBM Cloud Object Storage for changes? I've read the documentation and checked all the related links but can't find anything atm. I want a function that reacts on changes made in the object storage like the [follow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudant-follow) package does for Cloudant. I can't find anything like that for the [Cloud Object Storage package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-cos-sdk).

Answer (score 1):

At this time IBM Cloud Object Storage doesn't have support for generating notifications, although it is on the roadmap.